# Integrate Adobe Reader X to Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, adobe-reader

I am using Google Chrome as the default program to execute PDF file because it can be opened in tab and I can bookmark it for easy access later. But I do not use the default PDF viewer of Google Chrome, I want to use the Adobe Reader plugins instead because it has more convenient features than the default viewer. This works great with Adobe Reader 9. But when I update to Adobe Reader X, Chrome renders PDF files using its default PDF viewer, not the plugin. Anybody knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `chrome://plugins` into the address bar, find the `Chrome PDF Viewer`, and click `Disable`.

If it doesn't work, follow [these steps](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=142056).

*However*, if the your Adobe Reader's version is 10.1.3: it seems like there's an ongoing problem with Adobe Reader 10.1.3 for Google Chrome - see [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chrome/8MAt_8NDI3o). Some people have suggested several workarounds, but there is no solution yet.